# Ratio of random variables MGF? Please help.

Tags: probability, statistics

If we know the moment generating functions (MGFs) of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ to be $M_X(s)$ and $M_Y(s)$, respectively. The MGF of the sum $X+Y$ will $M_X(s)\cdot M_Y(s)$.

So what is the MGF of the ratio distribution $\frac XY$?

Comment: I don't expect it to be anything nice (or expressible in terms of $M_X(s)$ and $M_Y(s)$ without more integrals involved).

Comment: There may not even be a moment generating function. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and normal then $\frac XY$ does not have any finite moments

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no simple formula for that.  That is why it took a while for the Student $t$-distribution to be worked out, for example, as it is the ratio of a $Z$ normal variable and the square root of a chi-square random variable over its degrees of freedom.

Essentially you have to slog through the integrals on a case by case basis, I believe.